# Simple Jquery Selector Optimization in Functions

Tags: jquery, function, optimization, selector

```
var func = function () {    
    if (x) {
        $('.classA').doSomething;
    } else
        $('.classA').doSomethingElse;
};
```

I am curious about how functions are stored and run and how that affects Jquery selectors. I've read that it is ideal not to reuse selectors. If you are repeatedly trying to find an element with classA in successive lines of code, it is best to store the element reference and just call that. But in the above example, is there any value in creating an element reference variable and placing it outside the if/else statement? Such as:

```
var func = function () {
    var element = $('.classA');
    if (x) {
        element.doSomething;
    } else
        element.doSomethingElse;
};
```

It seems that in either case, Jquery will need to iterate through the DOM only once since in the first example, it will only run either the If, or the Else.

Now I know you could create the element reference outside of the function and store it into memory before ever running the function, but what if the element doesn't exist and is only created by a previous function that then runs my example here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance of both functions should be almost equal.

But with the second one you have benefits like:

- You can give the selected object a readable name (easier to find errors)
- It is cached in case you need it later (p.e. after refactoring)
- The selector consists of a string. If you made a typing mistake in the selector it will throw no error
- If you want to change the selector (p.e. classA -> classB) you need it only once